# django memcahed key generation

Tags: django, memcached

Default django cache keys generator:

```
def make_key(key, key_prefix, version):
    return ':'.join([key_prefix, str(version), key])
```

I want to change with:

in settings.py

```
def make_key(key, key_prefix, version):
    return key

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'KEY_FUNCTION' : 'settings.make_key',
        }
}
```

but django generate keys with old native function (prefix-version-key) how to change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
def make_key(key, key_prefix, version):
    return key

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'KEY_FUNCTION' : make_key
        }
}
```

I know that in documentation is "string containing a dotted path" but I see in the Django [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/backends/base.py#L28) that you can also pass callable object (eg. function).

If you really need to pass it as a string, you should move this function to another module and set `yourproject.module.make_key` as `KEY_FUNCTION`.